# String.split() doesn't work with my regex that searches for comma-separated items

Tags: java, regex

Could you please tell why my regex pattern which works in `String.matches()` doesn't split given string using `String.split` ?

Here is the code:

```
String text = "sdf.an@dfgdfg.com;   sdfsdf@fdfd.erff";
String regex = "(\\b[\\w.%-]+@[\\w.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}\\b)([,;]\\s*\\b[\\w.%-]+@[\\w.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}\\b)*";
String [] emails = text.split(regex);
```

`emails` is empty :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that `String.split` needs a delimiter not the whole pattern.

In your case you can simply put this

```
text.split(";\\s*")
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply use the regex `";\\s*"`?

```
String text = "sdf.an@dfgdfg.com;   sdfsdf@fdfd.erff";
String regex = ";\\s*";
String [] emails = text.split(regex);
for(String ss : emails) System.out.println(ss);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
sdf.an@dfgdfg.com
sdfsdf@fdfd.erff
```

Comment: tsk tsk: your regex *requires* there to be whitespace after the semicolon... maybe make it optional